# How can I solve endless backtracks in IntelliGen

Tags: specman

I wrote the following code:

```
struct packet {
    x:int;
    y:int;

    x >= 0 => y==1;
    x < 0 => y==2;
};
```

While it solved very fast in Specman, for some seeds the Gen Debugger shows that the generator tries to assign y to values different than 1 and 2 and even “y: set of rollbacks”.
What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

Since the generation engine doesn't know the valid space of y's values, it may try to solve it by assigning a random value for y in [MIN_INT..MAX_INT] and only then for x which leads for endless loop. 
You can solve it by to options:

1. Add

   keep y in [1,2]
2. Replace the constraints with

   keep y == (x >= 0) ? 1 : 0

Answer (score 0):

Using the trinary construct in this case, the generator can easily solve the constraint.

Answer (score 0):

In this case generation engine needs to infer information about y from 2 different constraints, which is expensive. Try to consolidate the constraints in single one and/or add information you already know to help it.

Answer (score 0):

You can help the generator by reducing the state space for the solution according to your intent.
It can be done in two ways
1. keep y in [1..2];
2. Consolidate the constraints
keep y == (x>0) ? 1 : 2;